# Dynamicaly Update the List in Html

Tags: javascript, html

I am having a List in html page, which should get Updated on the Click of Button.
I am also having a textfield and Button. value entered in textfield should display in listbox on click of Button.

This is my Code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>        
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function addsoap(form1)
            {
                if(document.form1.datafile.value=="")
                {
                    alert("Select a File First");
                }
                else
                {
                    var soap=document.getElementById("right1");
                    var newsoap=document.createElement('option');
                    newsoap.text=document.form1.datafile.value;
                    newsoap.value=document.form1.datafile.value;
                    soap.add(newsoap);
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table align='center'>
            <form name="form1">

                <tr>
                    <td>Please specify a file, or a set of files:<br>                    
                        <input type="file" name="datafile" size="40">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type=button value="ADD" onclick="addsoap(form1)" ></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right"><select id="right1" size="10" multiple>
                            <option>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</option>
                        </select></td>

                </tr>
            </form>

        </table>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add the code you already have and we maybe can help you!

Comment: You should show us some code and describe your problem more precise. What have you tried so far and what didn't work?

Comment: when i click add button list does not get updated with value entered in textfield.

Comment: i dont think `.add()` is a valid node method. have you tried [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.appendChild)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of .add method use .appendChild Method